# The package i have installed does not work. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-sunmi-inner-printer)

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, thermal-printer

I am having build issue after installing this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-sunmi-inner-printer

Anybody know why does the java stops at line 442?
Why does the compilation failed?

```
> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can
> disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag. Jetifier found 978 file(s) to
> forward-jetify. Using 4 workers... info Starting JS server... info
> Installing the app...
> 
> > Configure project :rn-sunmi-inner-printer WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and
> 'api'. It will be removed soon. For more information see:
> http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
> 
> > Task :rn-sunmi-inner-printer:compileDebugAidl
> 
> > Task :rn-sunmi-inner-printer:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> 
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> 16 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 5 up-to-date aidl.exe E 07-17
> 09:57:43  2252  6336 aidl.cpp:581] refusing to generate code from aidl
> file defining parcelable
> 
> C:\Users\User\Documents\Me\codes\AwesomeProject100\node_modules\rn-sunmi-inner-printer\android\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out\woyou\aidlservice\jiuiv5\IWoyouService.java:441:
> error: reached end of file while parsing case TRANSACTION_getForce
>                          ^ C:\Users\User\Documents\Me\codes\AwesomeProject100\node_modules\rn-sunmi-inner-printer\android\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out\woyou\aidlservice\jiuiv5\IWoyouService.java:442:
> error: reached end of file while parsing 2 errors
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':rn-sunmi-inner-printer:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> 
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
```

Comment: Upgrade your npm to the latest version.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff updated but it still does not work.